# Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:english_words/english_words.dart'.dart

Tags: visual-studio, dart, flutter

I am getting the above problem, updated the packages too by using the below command : 
"flutter packages upgrade".
Restarted the visual studio code, but didn't solve the problem.
Can anyone help me in resolving.

[image: screenshot]

Thanks.

Comment: Did you run `flutter packages get`? If so, can we see your pubspec.yaml file?

Comment: Yes, I did. Here in this comment section not able to insert the pubspec.yaml file.

Comment: That's really strange, it's seems that the package has glitched on the project or the IDE it's not fetching correctly. Can you show your flutter doctor? Run `flutter doctor -v` from the console

Comment: Sure.@FellipeMalta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure the alignment of `english_words` is correct inside your `pubspec.yaml` as it's "space sensitive" :

```
dependencies:
  english_words: ^(latest_version) //two spaces
```

also never align it using tabs, I don't know why but it never works.

Comment: put the `english_words` dependency exactly below `cupertino_icons` by adding space and run the `flutter packages get` command again

Comment: Thanks @Mazin Ibrahim

Comment: You're Welcome !

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, It work for me by adding: english_words: ^3.1.0
to the dev_dependencies:

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  english_words: ^3.1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem  for me targeted URI doesn't exist was due to the lib folder inside the english_words package was not available at
file:///E:/APPS/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/english_words/lib/
so I downloaded it from Github and add it there manually and restarted the IDE. And It worked.